# Unable to link changeset to an existing work item with TFS API

Tags: c#, azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

I am trying to link a changeset to an existing TFS workitem in C# with .NET client libraries for Azure DevOps Services (and TFS)

This is the code that I am using -

```
     public void CreateChangesetLinkAsync(int workitemID, int ChangesetId, string comment)
     {
         string changesetUrl = $"vstfs:///_versionControl/Changeset/{ChangesetId}";

         try
         {


            // Define the update operations using a JsonPatchDocument
             JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();
             patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation()
             {
                 Operation = Operation.Add,
                 Path = "/relations/-",
                 Value = new
                 {
                     rel = "ArtifactLink",
                     url =$"{changesetUrl}",
                     attributes = new {name = $"{comment}", LinkType = "Hyperlink" }

             }
             });

             // Send the update request
             WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = tfs.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
             witClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, workitemID).Wait();
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {

             throw;
         }


     }
```

but I get the same error every time...

VssServiceException: Unrecognized Resource link: Link Name: Merge changeset 377894 (workitem 174339) from Key2Dev322000 to TrunkSP Link Uri: vstfs:///_versionControl/Changeset/377986

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when using the similar sample.

[image]

To solve this issue, you need to change the following points in your code:

1.The correct Changeset URL format: `vstfs:///versionControl/Changeset/{ChangesetId}`. You need to remove the `_` in the link.

2.The name field in the attributes should be the value **Fixed in Changeset**.

```
attributes = new { name = "Fixed in Changeset", LinkType = "Hyperlink" }
```

If you need to add comment, you need to add the **comment** field.

**Update Sample:**

We need to add comment field to **attributes** .

```
 public void CreateChangesetLinkAsync(int workitemID, int ChangesetId, string comment)
 {
     string changesetUrl = $"vstfs:///versionControl/Changeset/{ChangesetId}";

     try
     {


        // Define the update operations using a JsonPatchDocument
         JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();
         patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation()
         {
             Operation = Operation.Add,
             Path = "/relations/-",
             Value = new
             {
                 rel = "ArtifactLink",
                 url =$"{changesetUrl}",
            
                 attributes = new {name = "Fixed in Changeset", comment = $"{comment}", LinkType = "Hyperlink" }

         }
         });

         // Send the update request
         WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = tfs.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
         witClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, workitemID).Wait();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {

         throw;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. that almost works. it links the changeset to the Work item but does not populate the link comment on the work item. Is that different to comment???

Comment: @TomWigley Let me check it. I will update later.

Comment: @TomWigley You can check the updated sample in the answer.  We need to add comment field to attributes . If the answer can help you solve the issue, you can consider accepting it.

Comment: I do have one question though - is this the best way to work with TFS? in so much as directly manipulating the JSON? or is there another (easier) way?